# GET Request Works from Mobile App but not from Flutter Web

Tags: laravel, flutter, get

I have a Laravel application. I have two apps on flutter that call the API on laravel. One mobile application - everything is fine with it - the GET request works. the second flutter for web - the GET request does not work. returns error code 405/(Method Not Allowed).

For reference, when I test this GET request via Postman, it works without any hitches, leading me to suspect the issue might reside in the CORS configuration.

Here's my CORS setup in Laravel:

'paths' => ['api/*', 'sanctum/csrf-cookie'],

```
'allowed_methods' => ['*'],

'allowed_origins' => ['*'],

'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],

//'allowed_headers' => ['*'],
'allowed_headers' => ['Content-Type', 'X-Requested-With', 'Authorization'],

'exposed_headers' => [],

'max_age' => 0,

'supports_credentials' => false,
```

Could someone provide insights or suggestions on what might be causing this discrepancy between the two Flutter applications? I'm particularly puzzled given that one works, and the other doesn't, despite both targeting the same endpoint.

Any advice - I will be very grateful